# Are there any kashrut issues with Kay Kosher?

Tags: hechsher-certification, hechsher

Are there any kashrut issues with Kay Kosher?

[image: Kay Kosher hashgakha]

Apparently it certifies U-Bet syrup. I grew up non-kosher but am currently keeping, and I want an egg cream.

Comment: Despite U-Bet's reputation, you can make an egg cream with Hershey's or other chocolate syrup also. In any event, note that you should contact your rabbi with practical questions rather than relying on what you read on this site.

Comment: I would suggest you take their certification letter http://www.webstaurantstore.com/documents/pdf/foxs_kosher.pdf to your LOR and have him review the standards and practices of the agency to see if they satisfy the requirements that he might have.

Comment: @Danno Since this is now March, you may want to get the updated certification for the current year. The link you used showed last year's certification.

Comment: @sabbahillel that's the letter I found. It would be reasonable background for someone who wanted to start making phone calls.

Answer (score 2):

I sent an email to the stark and got an answer that it is kosher when marked kosher for Passover on the cap.

**Update** I sent an email about the rest of the year received a statement that it is a recognized hechser.

> Yes, it is fine to use during the year.
>   Yes. Rabbi Shapiro certifies.

Here is the original response that I got from the Star-K  Kosher Certification star-k@star-k.org

> The label - in past has been around the cap- needs to say for
>   passover.
>
> If you need any further assistance, please feel free to contact us
>   again
>
> Many thanks